# 'truffle unpack' into windows directory from WSL ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, solidity, truffle

I have been following this tutorial, but am running into some errors:
https://medium.com/@m_mcclarty/setting-up-solidity-on-windows-10-993a1d2c615c

I am trying to use truffle unpack from a WSL ubuntu bash terminal, but keep running into a permissions error. I have tried running the command with sudo permissions, running WSL as administrator, and reinstalling npv, nodejs, npm and solcjs.

```
tobias@MSI:/mnt/c/Users/Tobias/desktop$ mkdir solidity
tobias@MSI:/mnt/c/Users/Tobias/desktop$ cd solidity
tobias@MSI:/mnt/c/Users/Tobias/desktop/solidity$ truffle unpack MetaCoin

Starting unbox...
=================

✔ Preparing to download box
✔ Downloading
✖ Downloading
Unbox failed!
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile '/tmp/tmp-1789-RNNADqNoi0dU/box/.gitattributes' -> '/mnt/c/users/Tobias/desktop/solidity/.gitattributes'
    at Object.copyFileSync (node:fs:2800:3)
    at copyFile (/home/tobias/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:67:1)
    at onFile (/home/tobias/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:53:1)
    at getStats (/home/tobias/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:48:1)
    at startCopy (/home/tobias/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:38:1)
    at handleFilterAndCopy (/home/tobias/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:33:1)
    at Object.copySync (/home/tobias/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:26:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tobias/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/box/dist/lib/utils/unbox.js:131:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/tobias/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/box/dist/lib/utils/unbox.js:5:42)
Truffle v5.4.19 (core: 5.4.19)
Node v17.1.0
tobias@MSI:/mnt/c/Users/Tobias/desktop/solidity$
```

If anyone has any more ideas about what the core issue may be, please let me know. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I created a VirtualBox Ubuntu virtual machine to do my homework.
Most likely, WSL is not a good tool for work with node JS with npm.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32980884)